# How to nest reference dll in visual studio 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i create a project **ClassLibrary1**,contain a method `Class1.Get1();`
then create a project **ClassLibrary2**,contain a method `Class2.Get2()`,and reference `ClassLibrary1.dll`
then create a project **ConsoleApplication1**,and reference `ClassLibrary2.dll,`
i just can call `Class2.Get2()` from ConsoleApplication1.Program,but 
how can i call `Class1.Get1()` but don't reference **ClassLibrary1.dll**
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference `ClassLibrary1` from `ConsoleApplication1` in order to be able to use it there.  You can't use an assembly (`ClassLibrary1`) referenced in another assembly (`ClassLibrary2`).

To answer your question about calling `Class1.Get1()` without referencing `ClassLibrary1.dll`, the easiest thing to do is probably just wrap `Class1.Get1()` in a method in `ClassLibrary2` somewhere.